Microphone Noisy After Ubuntu 24.04 Upgrade
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, and since then, my microphone has been super noisy and almost unusable.
My machine is Vivobook 16 and I use the internal microphone.
Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a reliable fix? I’d really appreciate any insights or solutions to get my mic back to normal. Thanks in advance!
➜  ~ inxi -Azy 1
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
    driver: N/A
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA
    v: k6.8.0-45-generic
    status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire
    v: 1.0.5
    status: active

Please let me know if there is a command I can run to give more information that could help

Do you have the necessary firmware for all devices on your laptop - sudo fwupdmgr get-devices?

I can't figure the answer of your question from the output but here is the full output https://gist.github.com/AhmedBaset/590beb3ec32e7f5ab9d842d184e0cbbe

Normally, after that command uploads data to remote server, it will return with a list of devices needing a firmware update.  If there was nothing returned, then I'd say all devices are up-to-date.

Please also check the output of sudo fwupdmgr get-updates.  It might be that I confused which command checks for update.

"No updates available"

Please add the output of inxi -Azy 1 to your post (you may need to install inxi if you don't have it installed yet sudo apt install inxi.  I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.1 and no one has complained that my audio is crappy sounding, yet!  See the output from my laptop at: https://pastebin.com/W8yYDRCZ

I added it to the post

What's the output of cat /proc/interrupts?  I'm looking to see if it could be an issue related to interrupt sharing.  Based off of this: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=3078.  It's an old one but who knows what could have regressed.

https://gist.github.com/AhmedBaset/590beb3ec32e7f5ab9d842d184e0cbbe#file-interrupts

Other than that you have 2 soundcards, it appears similar to mine.  Do you by any chance have pavucontrol installed?  You may want to check that things are connected as expected.  Also, sometimes having someone you can interact with via video conf can expedite resolution.

Nope: zsh: command not found: pavucontrol

Install it sudo apt install pavucontrol - it may help you in understanding what could be causing your issues.

This is the OP answer after some debugging. I'm documenting what worked for me. If you have a better approach please post an answer.
Go to Setting > Sound > Input > Input Volume

You can see on the top right of the screenshot a mic tester showing how much audio input it receives. When I took that screen shot I wasn't talking so all of that is noisy. You can adjust the Input Volume slider to match the best result for you.

This level is suitable to me
